# How can I disable the forward/back buttons in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I disable the Flash player forward and back button in AS3? These buttons make it possible to cheat in my game by moving from level to level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're referring to the default entries in the Flash-Player menu:

[image: flash player menu]

The entries there can be customize (to a certain degree) by using the [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) class.

Here's an example. In a frame of your timeline (preferrably at the beginning), place the following code:

```
var menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var items:ContextMenuBuiltInItems = new ContextMenuBuiltInItems();

// disable the undesired items from the built-in items
items.play = false;
items.rewind = false;
items.forwardAndBack = false;

menu.builtInItems = items;

// override the context menu with our own menu
this.contextMenu = menu;
```

Comment: @LocalLocas No problem. Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the checkmark) if it helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to disable that browser function in ac3. I wouldn't worry about cheating too much.

Comment: I think he's referring to the flash forward/back functions, not browser forward/back buttons